# What is spectral invariant?

Tags: differential-geometry, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, riemannian-geometry, spectral-theory, symplectic-geometry

Picture below is from *The Spectrum of the Laplacian in Riemannian
Geometry* . What is the mean of spectral invariant ? I google  spectral invariant , and find it is a notation of  symplectic geometry . But seemly, there is nothing about  symplectic geometry.

> [image]
>
> [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The term *spectral invariant* refers to an object, such as a function $Z$ of one real variable, defined in terms of a Riemannian manifold $(M, g)$ but that depends only on the spectrum of the $g$-Laplacian on the space of square-integrable functions on $M$.

Isometric manifolds obviously have equal spectral invariants, but the converse is not *a priori* apparent (and in fact not true, hence the concept of [*isospectral*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isospectral) manifolds and the field of [*spectral* geometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_geometry)).